# optional_param in form

Tags: php, moodle

I have a question about the optional_param function in a form in PHP (version 5.3.14)

After looking over why certain fields were not being saved in a form I have, I realised that this data...

```
$checkdata = optional_param('items', array(), PARAM_INT)
```

Only saves up to 996 places (items) from the form (they are select items and there are many)....

Is this a setting or a something I can change? or alternatively something wrong from my end?

Thanks in advance

---

Solution : A moodle function (platform i am working with)

Thanks Pekka

Comment: `optional_param` does not seem to be a PHP core function. Where do you have it from?

Comment: oh really? I am using moodle and it is in a php file and seems to work correctly... inside a function that gets called on saving a form

Comment: Seems to be a moodle function. Can you look at the incoming data - when it's at the 996th item, how big is the overall variable? What about the raw POST/GET data, is it cut as well? (`print_r($_POST);`)

Comment: you may be right... Thanks i will look into it tonight..

Answer (score 9):

this function is a moodle function. It gets a parameter from the current page URL.

For an example url:

```
http://moodle.dev/course/view.php?id=2&items=4
```

(this is chosen totally arbitrary)

Using this code:

```
$checkdata = optional_param('items', array(), PARAM_INT)
```

Will save the "items" value (here it's 4) in $checkdata. If items does not exist in the url it will do `$checkdata = array()`